# Maximum call stack size exceeded - shopify variant product with multiple currencies

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, callback, shopify

I have a shop on shopify which recently implemented this: 
https://help.shopify.com/themes/customization/currencies/show-multiple-currencies#Do_tell_where_the_money_is

However, now there is a an error in the console when viewing a product with variants (ex: color: red or orange)

> Uncaught RangeError: Maxiumum call stack size exceeded

Any idea how to make this work with variants?

page with error: https://borntoswim.eu/collections/swim-fins/products/adult-silicone-swim-fins-green

Comment: The error means you've got an infinite loop somewhere in your code. With the limited information you've provided, that's all the help we can really offer

Comment: thank you for the comment. I think I know why it happens. Will post a solution.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, the code that was causing this error was called in the webpage two times. After removing the duplicate, it works like a charm :). Hope this helps someone.